# Mocking a class instance affects the static instance initialization

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I run into an issue that, if I mock a class instance, then a static instance in the same class is not initialized correctly.

I have a real example of third party code with relevant to the question lines:

```java
...
public class Schema implements SchemaProvider
{
    public static final Schema instance = new Schema();

    private volatile Keyspaces distributedKeyspaces = Keyspaces.none();

    private final Keyspaces localKeyspaces;

    private final boolean online;

    ...

    private Schema()
    {

        this.online = isDaemonInitialized();
        this.localKeyspaces = (FORCE_LOAD_LOCAL_KEYSPACES || isDaemonInitialized() || isToolInitialized())
                              ? Keyspaces.of(SchemaKeyspace.metadata(), SystemKeyspace.metadata())
                              : Keyspaces.none();
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public Schema(boolean online, Keyspaces localKeyspaces)
    {
        this.online = online;
        this.localKeyspaces = localKeyspaces;
    }
    ...
```

Then the project jar is used in another project where `Schema` is mocked in a test:

```java
Schema schema = Mockito.mock(Schema.class);
```

To my understanding this should not affect the static instance initialization, i.e., `Schema.instance`. However, I run into an issue that the static instance is not initialized correctly and its properties are `null`, i.e.:

```java
assert Schema.instance.distributedKeyspaces == null;
assert Schema.instance.localKeyspaces == null;
```

I've found that I can workaround the initialization issue in my test project by creating a dummy instance:

```java
new Schema(false, Keyspaces.none());
Schema schema = Mockito.mock(Schema.class);
// which gives me:
assert Schema.instance.distributedKeyspaces != null;
assert Schema.instance.localKeyspaces != null;
```

I have failed to find any information about this use case. So I would love to hear explanation of this behaviour and if it is expected or some uncommon usage, which runs in a kind of undefined behaviour. Is there a better way to workaround the issue? (preferably without changing the third-party library)

Java version: openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20

Mockito version: 3.5.0

Comment: A mock creates a proxy, a proxy has nothing initialized and thus everything is `null`. This is expected behavior and you run into this because of the weird usage here.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you elaborate? What happens in the case of `public static final Schema instance = new Schema()`? Does the proxy replace the constructor during loading `Schema` class? I guess it cannot avoid loading `Schema`, since all the methods of `Schema.instance` are callable, just properties are not initialized (initialized to `null`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Schema.class` loads the class `Schema` but doesn't initialize it. So when `Mockito.mock` is called to create the proxy object, the class is initialized, but constructing `Schema` for static final `instance` is not done properly for some reason. I have empirical evidence, but no references to docs or code. I asked about in [Mockito issue tracker](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2647)

So the solution is to make sure that the class is loaded and initialized before calling Mockito. E.g., by calling [`Class.forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)):

```java
Class.forName(Schema.class.getName());
// and then mock
Schema schema = Mockito.mock(Schema.class);
```

or

```java
Schema schema = Mockito.mock((Class<Schema>)Class.forName(Schema.class.getName()));
```